# Persistent queue in C# service

Tags: c#, sql, service, network-programming, message-queue

I need to implement a persistent queue in my C# service. It polls data from an external source. After it received a unit of data, it shall send it to a server. If the sending fails, it shall write it to disk in a queue-manner and try to resend it with an interval but also continue to poll the data and thus keep fill up the queue. I need to save it to disk because the network can fail and meanwhile the server can be shutdown. Resulting in a restart of the service and thus in-memory queue deleted. (Of course no polling will be made during reboot but the data during the network failure before will be lost).

I have now solved this problem by implementing a queue in Sql CE. After it polls the data, it directly writes it to the sql ce database, another thread then reads (peek) the database and tries to send the data. If it managed to send it, the message gets dequeued. I feel this solution is quite heavy and not very efficient.

Do anyone have experience with similar scenario and tips of how to implement it in a better way?

Comment: Did you consider [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: You could use `RabbitMq`. There is an excellent library for C#: [`EasyNetQ`](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ)

Comment: I do not want to install any "other" software. I need to be able to include it in my service, that is possible? Would those tools be faster than Sql CE?

Comment: I am also looking for some sort of file based persistent queue to use in c#